# How to create a select statement that request from 2 tables

Tags: query

How can i combine this two request in 1 single request in ios:

```
NSString *theRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Name, OpportunityID FROM OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityID = '%@'", [companyDic objectForKey:@"Id"]];
SFRestRequest *request = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery:theRequest];
[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request delegate:self];
```

and

```
NSString *theRequest2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT CompetitorName FROM OpportunityCompetitor where OpportunityID = '%@'", [companyDic objectForKey:@"Id"]];
SFRestRequest *request2 = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery:theRequest2];
[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request2 delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the question was how to use SOQL/Apex to do this the answer would be a [relationship query](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) to pull values from all 3 tables:

```
Opportunity opp = [
        select
                Id, Name,
                (select Quantity from OpportunityLineItems),
                (select CompetitorName from OpportunityCompetitors)
        from Opportunity
        where Id = '...'
        ];
OpportunityLineItem[] items = opp.OpportunityLineItems;
OpportunityCompetitor[] competitors = opp.OpportunityCompetitors;
```

From a cursory reading of the Salesforce Mobile SDK Development Guide it looks like that SOQL pattern will work for iOS too.

(I don't see a Name field in OpportunityLineItem.)

Comment: how to use this on ios?.

Comment: The select is just a string that can replace your current select string (keeping the substitution syntax you are using for the opportunity ID) and the response comes back as JSON. So once the JSON is parsed there will be array fields called OpportunityLineItems and  OpportunityCompetitors that you can loop over. But let me repeat that I didn't read the iOS documentation at all carefully but you should.